# Kohana Auth Library Deployment

Tags: authentication, deployment, kohana

My Kohana app runs perfectly on my local machine.

When I deployed my app to a server (and adjust the config files appropriately), I can no longer log into the app.

I've traced through the app login routine on both my local version and the server version and they both agree with each other all the way through until you get to the auth.php controller **logged_in()** routine where suddenly, at line 140 - the is_object($this->user) test - the $user object no longer exists!?!?!?

The **login()** function call that calls the **logged_in()** function successfully passes the following test, which causes a redirect to the **logged_in()** function.

```
if(Auth::instance()->login($user, $post['password']))
```

Yes, the password and hash, etc all work perfectly.

Here is the offending code:

```
public function logged_in()
{
    if ( ! is_object($this->user))
    {
    // No user is currently logged in
    url::redirect('auth/login'); 
    }
etc...
}
```

As the code is the same between my local installation and the server, I reckon it must be some server setting that is messing with me.

FYI: All the rest of the code works because I have a temporary backdoor available that allows me to use the application (view pages of tables, etc) without being logged in.

Any ideas?

Comment: What auth method are you using? ORM or File?  If file, is the file being read properly?  I would dig into the Kohana_Auth_XXX class you're using and trace the call to find out where it's failing.

Comment: I'm using ORM and I know the database is being accessed as my tracing of the routines showed me what info it was fetching.  According to watching what code is being run, the login IS successful, it just fails to return the $this->user object at the final step (i.e. the user is logged in but the system isn't aware of it).


BTW: I did trace (watch variables) through the Kohana_Auth_XXX class and it is fine.  It is the journey from the exit of the login() function to the entry of the logged_in() function that the object is getting unset.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem (DUH!).

The answer was that the cookie.php config file had **$config['domain'] = 'localhost'**.  Setting this to the actual domain that the app is installed in magically made my life happy again!

Thanks everyone for your help and interest.